# I pushed my application to zapier platform, trying to create zap templates, but cant see my app in the list

Tags: zapier

I created my app Onshape and used it in Zaps. The triggers and actions are working fine, but when I try to create a zap template, the dropdown to select the trigger app doesn't show my app? Is there any setting that I need to enable to see my Onshape app in the list?

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Per [the docs](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/app-lifecycle/#welcome-to-early-access):

> You won't yet be able to create Zap Templates at this time, that capability is enabled once your integration reaches the public/beta step.